# Proxy server as DHCP

Tags: proxy, ip, dhcp

I want to create proxy server which will give different users different ip's.
Which instrument I can do it with?

eth0 has many aliased ip adresses.
Human connecting to the proxy(squid? 3proxy?) must be detected by other sites with unique ip address from ip's aliased to eth0.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want users that are having their connections proxied by your squid box be seen as if they were coming from one of the aliased ip's (bases on some criteria as to which users use which IP)?

Comment: Yes!
And it wood be good if each user have a static ip address. If he reconnects to the proxy he must have the same ip as the previous session.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you really need?  In sounds like you need a VPN, not a proxy.

Comment: I need proxy server, not vpn. It is technical requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy servers and DHCP servers are two different things (usually).  If you need a small flexible DHCP server on linux, I'd suggest dnsmasq.  It'll also let you handle things like naming machines on your local network if you use the DNS aspects of it.

If you want a web proxy, you'll need to look at something like squid, or dansguardian, depending on what kind of proxying you want.

As MarkM says, your question isn't very clear, and you need to do more research to figure out what you actually want/need I think, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: I've edited my question. I need web proxy which will give users different ips.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just install and configure dhcpd on the same box that you're proxying with, assuming you're using *nix. If you're using Windows, just install the DHCP Server role and configure accordingly.

Did I miss the point? The question isn't very clear.

Comment: I've adited my question. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, even after the edit. You can't assign an IP address to a machine based on the user who is logged in, which is how I interpret the question. To do something like that you would need to create a custom application because that's not how DHCP works.

Comment: I want proxy server to assign custom external ip for each user session.
I wrote wrong analogy with dhcp.

Comment: Proxies don't assign IP addresses, so I'm still confused.